# 4. Тестирование способности Gunicorn обслуживать проект

Tags: gunicorn

установлен проект django
Мне нужно Тестирование способности Gunicorn обслуживать проект
ввожу
gunicorn --bind 10.52.2.16:8081 cre.wsgi
Но получаю ошибку

````
[2021-12-08 10:57:14 +0500] [101418] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-12-08 10:57:14 +0500] [101418] [INFO] Listening at: http://10.52.2.16:8081 (101418)
[2021-12-08 10:57:14 +0500] [101418] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-12-08 10:57:14 +0500] [101421] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 101421
[2021-12-08 10:57:14 +0500] [101421] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/CreditReg/credit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/admin/CreditReg/credit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/admin/CreditReg/credit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/admin/CreditReg/credit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/admin/CreditReg/credit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/admin/CreditReg/credit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/admin/CreditReg/credit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangoProject'
[2021-12-08 10:57:14 +0500] [101421] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 101421)
[2021-12-08 10:57:15 +0500] [101418] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-12-08 10:57:15 +0500] [101418] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.```
````

Answer (score 0):

У Вас же черно по белому написано:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangoProject'
```

Импортируйте этот модуль и будет счастье.

Скорее всего Вы запускаете не из той папки проект и поэтому он его не видит. Проверьте пути запуска

Comment: Я не знаю из какой папки он должен запусаться, у меня просто инструкция в которй просто указано, что надо выполнить эту команду. Я создал 2 директории 
mkdir ~/CreditReg
cd ~/ CreditReg затем виртуальную среду  virtualenv credit

Comment: Вы же должны указывать путь к запуску проекта, иначе gunicorn откуда будет знать что откуда брать?

Comment: затем я ставлю прокет git clone https://git.etf-int.ru/nolan/credit-registry.git у меня появляется каталог credit-registry с пакетами, но ни cre credit credit-registry пишут,что нет такого модуля

Comment: @Alexey, Наверное, Вы склонировали прямо папкой и соответственно в пути появился лишний каталог. Посмотрите внимательнее в инструкции скорее всего требуется сделать клонирование в пустую папку и только потом открыть проект и создать там виртуальное окружение. PS если клонируете и в конце стоит точка - значит клонирование происходит без папки проекта(а это можно только в пустую папку).

Comment: sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv
 mkdir ~/CreditReg
cd ~/ CreditReg 
virtualenv credit  source credit/bin/activate  pip install django gunicorn psycopg2-binary Скачиваем проект git clone https://git.etf-int.ru/nolan/credit-registry.git Прежде всего, необходимо изменить настройки созданных файлов проекта. Откройте файл настроек в текстовом редакторе nano или напрмер в mc(ставится отдельно) по пути 
~/CreditReg/credit/credit-registry/djangoProject/djangoProject>
nano ~/CreditReg/cred/settings.py

Comment: Установить 'rest_framework' 
pip3 install djangorestframework
 'requests'
pip3 install requests
~/CreditReg/credit/credit-registry/djangoProject>python3 manage.py makemigrations
~/CreditReg/credit/credit-registry/djangoProject> python3 manage.py migrate /CreditReg/credit/credit-registry/djangoProject>python3 manage.py runserver 10.52.2.16:8081Перед выходом из виртуальной среды нужно протестировать способность Gunicorn обслуживать приложение. Для этого нам нужно войти в каталог нашего проекта  gunicorn для загрузки модуля WSGI 
cd ~/CreditrReg gunicorn --bind 10.52.2.16:8081 cre.wsgi

Comment: @Alexey, wsgi.py - это файл, который запускает Ваш проект. Все пути начинаются от него. Соответственно для Gunicorn Вы указываете путь именно к этому файлу. А он уже и запустит Ваш проект. Смотрите Чтобы при подключении модулей - все находились на своих местах относительно файла "wsgi.py"

Comment: у мена путь выглядит так до файла wsgy.py  /home/admin/CreditReg/credit/credit-registry/djangoProject/djangoProject/ я не понимаю какое имя проекта или модуля надо писать gunicorn --bind 10.52.2.16:8081 venv.wsgi:application выдает ошибку No module named 'venv.wsgi'

Comment: @Alexey, Если это не Ваш проект, то сначала попробуйте запустить его у себя на ноутбуке локально, чтобы найти файл от которого у Вас запускается проект. Если Вы сможете запустить проект на ноутбуке через файл wsgi.py, значит это и есть файл запуска. PS: рекомендую к прочтению статью про запуск проекта на Django: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru